# How can I filter results from a complex SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, subquery, filtering

I have a sql query like so:

```
SELECT  `categories`.`partnumbersafe`, `filters`.`filtername`,  `filters`.`filtervalue` 
FROM  `products_categories` AS  `categories` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `products` AS  `product` ON  `categories`.`partnumbersafe` =  `product`.`partnumbersafe` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `products_filters` AS  `filters` ON  `categories`.`partnumbersafe` =  `filters`.`partnumbersafe` 
WHERE  `categories`.`categoryid` =4
AND (`product`.`visibility` =1 OR  `product`.`visibility` =2)
AND  `product`.`status` =1
```

This gives me a result where there are multiple partnumbersafe entries (same value) with different filternames and filtervalues. For example:

```
partnumbersafe   filtername   filtervalue

123                brand        toyota
123                model        F5
123                type         business
678                brand        toyota
678                model        F6
```

The query is generated by PHP. I also have POST values in my PHP script which hold filterdata (brand is toyota, model is F6 for example).

How can I filter these results for filtername/value pairs? I would prefer a sql query solution instead of a php solutiuon, where I can query for partnumbersafe where brand is toyota and model is F6. So that it would only retrieve partnumbersafe 123 in the above table.

The table products_filters holds all the data as represented by the table outline above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `categories`.`partnumbersafe`
FROM
  `products_categories` AS  `categories` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `products`            AS  `product`
    ON  `categories`.`partnumbersafe` = `product`.`partnumbersafe` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `products_filters`    AS  `filters`
    ON  `categories`.`partnumbersafe` = `filters`.`partnumbersafe` 
WHERE
     `categories`.`categoryid` = 4
AND (`product`.`visibility` =1 OR  `product`.`visibility` =2)
AND  `product`.`status` =1
AND
(
  (`filters`.`filtername` = 'Brand' AND `filters`.`filtervalue` = 'Toyota')
  OR
  (`filters`.`filtername` = 'Model' AND `filters`.`filtervalue` = 'F6')
)
GROUP BY
  `categories`.`partnumbersafe`
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

This assumes that you only need the `partnumbersafe` ***and*** that no `filtername`/`filtervalue` pair would ever apply to the same `partnumbersafe` more than once.

Comment: Also, because of these filters, you don't need `LEFT JOIN`, you can just use `INNER JOIN` - Anything without a filter record will be excluded by the `WHERE` clause anyway...

Comment: Dems, if I would also need the filtername Brand value for each query, is that possible?

Comment: Could you give an example in your question?

Comment: Basically I would like to return filters.filtervalue for the brand along with the partnumbersafe.

SELECT
  `categories`.`partnumbersafe`
  `filters.filtervalue`
FROM....
WHERE `filters`.`filtername` = 'BRAND'

Comment: @MarcBuurke - But, in your case, that will always be the value you searched for, won't it?  If you search for `Toyota`, the brand of the parts return are always `Toyota`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I see where my question is not clear. What I meant was, how can I return the brand value, when using only the model filter in the original question. So basically, return all partnumbers with their brands for model 'F6' (assuming that say toyota and ford both have a F6 model)

Comment: @MarcBuurke - The generic way would be to join these results back on to your parts table, using this as a sub-query.  `SELECT * FROM (queryFromAnswer) AS subQuery LEFT JOIN products_filters AS filter ON subQuery.partnumbersafe = filter.partnumbersafe AND filter.filtername = 'Brand'`

Answer (score 2):

you need to have multiple condition here. The number of record for each `partnumbersafe` is equal to the number of condition you supplied.

```
SELECT partnumbersafe
FROM...
WHERE (filterName = 'Brand' AND filtervalue = 'toyota')
        OR
      (filterName = 'Model' AND filtervalue = 'F6')
GROUP BY partnumbersafe
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks John, could you elaborate a bit more? Do you mean select from the above query as a whole? Or add that to the query as shown. In the latter case there would be no results, because there is no row in the table which holds both values, these are distributed across multiple rows.

Comment: basically it's the query you need. replace `FROM...` with you original `FROM` clause. be sure to include table name or `alias` on the column to avoid ambiguity error.

Comment: @MarcBuurke - This is the same as my answer. It starts by finding rows with `'Brand','Toyota'` ***OR*** `'Model','F6'`. Then it groups up by the `PartNumberSafe` value, but ***only*** returns results which have 2 source rows in the group. This means you now have a list of `PartNumberSafe` that have both a `'Brand','Toyota'` row ***AND*** a `'Model','F6'` row...

Comment: additional to @Dems comment, `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` was added to filter only rows that have 2 instances on the result because it matches to both coupled condition.